# Changing drive in NERDTree (gVim, Windows)

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, nerdtree

If NERDTree starts up somewhere in the C: drive, once I reach C:\ itself (which NERDTree considers as "/"), I get the message "already at top dir" if I try to click on the double dot `..`

NERDTree's help is all about navigating up and down directories, but there doesn't seem to be a way to directly specify a path to change to. Is there? Or is there any other way of switching drives on Windows?

Edit: I found the roundabout way of: changing Vim's directory with `:cd D:\`, then `:NERDTreeCWD`. Is there a better, more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:NERDTree /path/to/dir
```

opens NERDTree in the specified directory.

It is generally a better idea to start Vim in the directory you wich to work in, though.